# What is the word that best suits this type of behaviour of person?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Suppose a person is asking others to do something which he himself does not follow, what is the best word that can be used to describe this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could describe them as a **hypocrite**.

Via Dictionary.com:

> of the nature of hypocrisy, or pretense of having virtues, beliefs,
>   principles, etc., that one does not actually possess

Though this may miss the 'preaching' aspect of it.

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for the term hypocrite but the definition seemed to be different in different websites. So I was confused :(

Comment: Upvoted because the OP probably doesn't know they can "accept" an answer.